# Pre-commit does not allow GPG code-signing?

Tags: git, gnupg, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

We sign each commit with GPG2 for security purposes. Usually this involves a full-terminal-window "popup" asking you to enter a password after running `git commit` (the terminal screen is replaced with just the GPG message). However we have started using python's pre-commit tool run linting prior to committing, and the "pop-up" isn't appearing. Here is the error I get:

```
$ git commit -m "fix linting issues"
autopep8 wrapper.........................................................Passed
Flake8...................................................................Passed
Check python ast.........................................................Passed
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
Check JSON...............................................................Passed
Check for merge conflicts................................................Passed
Check for case conflicts.................................................Passed
Check Yaml...............................................................Passed
Debug Statements (Python)................................................Passed
Detect Private Key.......................................................Passed
Fix double quoted strings................................................Passed
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Forbid new submodules....................................................Passed
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
Pretty format JSON.......................................................Passed
pylint...................................................................Passed

error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Comment: What kind of `pinentry` program do you use? `pinentry-curses`? Do you use `gpg-agent`? Have you configured environment variable `GPG_TTY`?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, as was [the individual who reported it to the bug tracker](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1063) -- is it possible you waited too long and didn't enter your gpg key passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today. My configuration uses gpg-agent along with an Xorg-based pinentry application

Restoring the pre-pre-commit behavior required adding `no-tty` to the existing `gpg-agent.conf` after enabling `pre-commit`

It's not an issue or bug with `pre-commit`, but installing `pre-commit` into an otherwise functional `gpgsign` enabled repository can effectively "break" signing depending on your configuration